# Cómo encontrar en el código de google el número de resultados aproximados que tiene la búsqueda

Tags: java, android, html, android-asynctask, google-search

Estoy realizando un trabajo que trata de mostrar, desde una app móvil el número de resultados aproximados que genera una búsqueda en google.

En esencia, busco la frase que sale justo debajo de las pestañas "todo imagenes noticias videos", esa en la que pone "Aproximadamente [numero] resultados ([tiempo] segundos)".
Mi problema es que no la encuentro en el código fuente de google (botón derecho>ver código fuente de página), ¿alguna idea sobre dónde buscarla?

Mi aplicación imprime el código fuente entero, en esta parte no hay problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mediante el uso de la API de búsqueda personalizado [Documentación](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#WorkingResults)

Sólo tienes que hacer un GET, que regresará un JSON con la información.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&cx={YOUR_SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}&q={YOUR_SEARCH_STRING}&alt=json&fields=queries(request(totalResults))
```

En la documentación dice "Prerequisites", y ahi sale explicado como obtener los valores que necesitas. por ejemplo
YOUR_API_KEY: la encuentras (si es que ya has generado): [[acá]](https://console.developers.google.com/)

[Respuesta Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569381/get-number-of-google-search-results/11569731#11569731)

También puede interesarte una respuesta en [jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401466/how-to-get-resultstats-from-google-using-jsoup/34808872#34808872)  o en [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377504/perform-a-google-search-and-return-the-number-of-results/29379918#29379918)

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez podrías hacer esto:

1. Obtener el HTML de la búsqueda.
2. Obtener el texto utilizando:

JQuery

```
$( "#resultStats" ).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Según he entendido, lo que buscas es la forma de obtener el HTML de Google y que éste contenga el elemento #resultStats que guarda la frase: "Aproximadamente x resultados (x segundos)".

Pues bien, seguramente utilizas una URL así para obtener el HTML: "https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=prueba"

El problema con ese URL es que no ejecuta la búsqueda, simplemente pasa el parámetro que tiene que buscar y la búsqueda se realiza por ajax cuando carga la página, eso quiere decir que el HTML que recibirás será el del inicio de Google y no el de los resultados de la búsqueda.

Para que el HTML devuelva la búsqueda hecha, debes utilizar este URL: "https://www.google.es/search?q=prueba"

Para extraer los datos del HTML, recomiendo jsoup (para java) que es muy sencillo de utilizar y funciona de forma parecida a jQuery de javascript.